# Indefinite Integral of $\sqrt{\sin x}$

Tags: integration

$$\int \sqrt{\sin x} ~dx.$$

Does there exist a simple antiderivative of $\sqrt{\sin x}$? How do I integrate it?

Comment: It does not have an elementary antiderivative. If calculating this integral is a step in a wider problem, it might be worth posting the wider problem, because it's likely that you've gone wrong somewhere in your working.

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sqrt{\sin x}~dx ~=~ \int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sqrt{\cos x}~dx ~=~ 2\sqrt\pi~\frac{\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac34\bigg)}{\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac14\bigg)}~.~$ See [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals) for more details.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{\sin(x)} = \sqrt{1 - 2 \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4} -\frac{x}{2}\right)}$, this matches with the [elliptic integral of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind):
$$\begin{align*}
   \int \sqrt{\sin(x)} \, \mathrm{d} x &\stackrel{u = \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}}{=} -2 \int \sqrt{1-2 \sin^2(u)} \,\mathrm{d} u\\ &= -2 E\left(u\mid 2\right) + c =  -2 E\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\middle|\, 2\right) + c
\end{align*}$$
where $c$ is an integration constant.

Comment: I fixed your delimiters. Remember: [comma for modulus, bar for parameter!](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/108659)