# how to integrate sqrt(sin(x)).without using elliptic integration .

Tags: integration

How do you solve 
$$
\int\sqrt{\sin(t)}dt 
$$
using the substitution method.

Comment: that one is solved in a different way.

Comment: i did this in two more different ways a long time ago just cant recall that's why i put it as such. i was somehow able to convert this in a polynomial type.

Comment: You can get something like this: $\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt\sin x\sqrt\cos x dx$ in terms of the gamma function. Then use a simple trigonometric  substitution. (See Whittaker and Watson p.256 . But it isn't elementary and it's a definite integral.)

Comment: i think i can solve it  i'll put answer after a few days.

Comment: https://archive.org/stream/courseofmodernan00whit#page/256/mode/2up           ;) nice book.

Comment: Really duplicate to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177709? OP want this question to avoid using elliptic functions, while http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177709 has not this restriction.