# Heuman Lambda Function in MATLAB

Tags: integration, special-functions, matlab, elliptic-integrals

I'm trying to implement the Heuman Lambda function in MATLAB, but i'm having problems getting a correct answer.

The Heuman Lambda Function is:

$$ \Lambda_0(\beta,k) = \frac{2}{pi}[E(k)F(\beta,k') + K(k)E(\beta,k') - K(k)F(\beta,k')] $$

Where E(k) and K(k) are the complete elliptic integrals of the first and second kind, and E($\beta$,k) and F($\beta$,k) are the incomplete elliptic integrals of the first and second kind.

K(k) = complete elliptic integral of the first kind

$$K(k) = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {1}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 sin^2 \theta} }d\theta$$

E(k) = complete elliptic integral of the second kind

$$E(k) = \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1 - k^2 sin^2 \theta }d\theta$$

F($\beta$,k) = incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind

$$F(\beta,k) = \int_0^{\beta} \frac {1}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 sin^2 \theta} }d\theta$$

E($\beta$,k) = incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind

$$E(\beta,k) = \int_0^{\beta} {\sqrt{1 - k^2 sin^2 \theta} }d\theta$$

Here is my attempt so far

```
function [ HL ] = Heuman_Lambda( b,k )

b = b*pi/180;    %see note 1

k = sin(k*pi/180)^2;    %see note 2 

kdash = (1-(k^2))^0.5;    %see note 3

[K,E] = ellipke(k);

incF = ellipticF(b,kdash);

incE = ellipticE(b,kdash);

HL = 2/pi * (E*incF + K*incE - K*incF );
```

note 1: This is because MATLAB works in radians, but the table of answers I have uses degrees for $\beta$

note 2: This is because in the MATLAB implementation of the 1st and 2nd complete elliptic integrals the equation is slightly different. See [MATLAB ellpipke](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/ellipke.html) at the bottom for an explanation. Also see [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627956/how-to-compute-elliptic-integrals-in-matlab) I have asked on the subject where it was explained to me.

note 3 :This is because in [This Document](http://www.umich.edu/~ners312/Course%20Library/SolidAngleOfADiskOffAxis.pdf) on page 256, just under equation 17, it says that this will compute k'

I have tried many variations of this code, but I cannot get an accurate answer. I am certain that the individual elliptic integral functions are correct for k and $\beta$, as I have individually tested all four of them and compared them to a table of answers I have. I do not have a table of answers for k' however so this may be where I am going wrong.

Here is the table of answers I have for the Heuman Lambda function:

```
(sin^-1)k                b
    -     |    0    |    5    |    10 
----------------------------------
    0     |    0    | 0.08716 | 0.17364
    30    |    0    | 0.08143 | 0.16225
    60    |    0    | 0.06723 | 0.13413

(sin^-1)k and b are both in degrees
```

These do not agree with the answers I am getting for my function. Does anybody know where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `k` is what the theory calls $k^2$, so your `kdash` should use `k` instead of `k^2` (the latter would represent $k^4$)

Comment: And since Matlab wants to be given $k^2$ in `ellipke` and probably in `ellipticF` and `ellipticE` as well, it probably also wants to be given $k'^2=1-k^2$ which is `1-k` in your notation. That is, no explicit squareroot seems to be needed.

Comment: Thank you so much! The function now works perfectly. You have no idea how long i've been struggling with this. God I love this website.

Comment: [For reference.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108659)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post an answer so that I can close this question.

The code to implement the Heuman Lambda Function in MATLAB is:

```
function [ HL ] = Heuman_Lambda( b,k )

b = b*pi/180;

k = sin(k*pi/180)^2;

kdash = (1-k);

[K,E] = ellipke(k);

incF = ellipticF(b,kdash);

incE = ellipticE(b,kdash);

HL = 2/pi * (E*incF + K*incE - K*incF );
```

Be aware that the elliptic integrals ellipicF and ellipticE do not work straight away. You first have to create a matlab function for these calling them from the MUPAD. To do this:

```
function [ F ] = ellipticF( phi,k )

y = feval(symengine,'ellipticF',phi,k);

F = double(y);

end
```

And do the same for ellipticE