# Heuman function in Matlab - intersection between sphere and cylinder

Tags: integration, matlab, volume, intersection-theory, elliptic-integrals

I am trying to calculate the volume of the intersection between a sphere and a cylinder given the variables of the displacement between the 2 centers and the cylinder radius.
[The volume is given by the formula seen in the screen dump and the Heuman function is a part of that expression.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1ysw.png)

I have tried the code for the Heuman Lambda Function described in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628216/heuman-lambda-function-in-matlab/4191649#4191649)
and adjusted it a bit, since I do not use angles in degrees. However, it does not seem to work, since the calculated volumes do not agree with the tabulated results in the [article](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82412251.pdf).

Can anyone help me to solve the problem? Is it something with the inputs due to different definitions in Matlab and the text? The code looks like this.

```
% volume of the intersection between a sphere and a cylinder
clc, clear, close

rho = 1; % radius of the cylinder
nu = 1.5; % distance between the 2 centers
% rho+nu

v = asin(nu-rho) % argument to Heuman function
k = sqrt((1-(nu-rho)^2)/(4*nu*rho)) % argument to Heuman function

H_1 = Heuman_Lambda_1(v,k)
V_1A = volume_1A(rho,nu,k,H_1)

function [V_1A] = volume_1A(rho,nu,k,H_1) % nu > rho and nu + rho > 1, Ms intersects Mc in 2 points

[K,E] = ellipke(k);
V_1A = (2*pi/3)*(1-H_1)-(8/9)*sqrt(rho*nu)*(6*rho^2+2*rho*nu-3)*(1-k^2)*K+(8/9)*sqrt(rho*nu)*(7*rho^2+nu^2-4)*E;

end

function [HL_1] = Heuman_Lambda_1(v,k) 

kdash = (1-k);

[K,E] = ellipke(k);

incF = ellipticF(v,kdash);

incE = ellipticE(v,kdash);

HL_1 = 2/pi * (E*incF + K*incE - K*incF);
end
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164/

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The inputs to the Matlab functions are the squared moduli, $k^2$. Hence, the `kdash` in the code should be $1-k^2$ and `[K,E] = ellipke(k^2)` has now a squared modulus.
Thanks anyway.