# How do I apply the product (capital pi) symbol here?

Tags: integration, notation, special-functions

I know $\prod$ is the product symbol but I'm not sure how to apply it in the result shown below.  The $a$, $b$, and $d$ are constants.

$$\frac{\prod\left(\frac{(b - a)(b + a)}{d^2 + b^2}\,;x\,\middle|\,\frac{(b - a)(b + a)}{d^2 + b^2}\right)}{(d^2 + b^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$$

Any help appreciated.  By the way, this result above came from the integration of this: $1/(d^2 + b^2\cos^2x+a^2\sin^2x)^\frac{3}{2}$

EDIT:  How do I evaluate that result to a numerical result? (e.g. With integration limits $0$ to $2\pi$)

Comment: How, then, did you come across that result, if you say that you're doing this by hand?

Comment: You didn't ask me how I came across the result, you asked me how I was going to be evaluating it.  I arrived at the integral  by working through the mechanics of deriving the magnetic field due to current flowing around a loop of wire in shape of ellipse.  When I got to that integral I could not work it so I plugged it in to an online tool that integrates for you.  Hence the result with the capital pi that I did not know how to evaluate to a numerical solution.  This is not some school problem, I'm 50 years old.

Comment: I did not assume this was a school problem at all. :) I was just curious about the situation that led you to an elliptic integral. In any event: I totally missed that you mentioned the integration limits; in that case, it is possible that you have a *complete* elliptic integral, and you can use AGM if you really want to compute things by hand, and are alright with taking square roots. I'll need to think about it...

Comment: Thank you J.M.   I would appreciate any direction you can afford me.  No hurry.

Comment: Also, I have Mathcad and Matlab if there is a way to evaluate with those tools.  I would much prefer to understand how to evaluate by hand too.  I am not in a hurry here, I am trying to really get a good physical grasp of this problem I am working on.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician  Have you had a chance to think about this?  I have read quite a bit but still don't know how to evaluate with real numbers to a numerical result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is not the product symbol. It is the [incomplete elliptic integral of the third kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_third_kind) (A non-elementary function).

It is defined as:

$$\Pi(n ; \varphi \,|\,m) = \int_{0}^{\sin \varphi} \frac{1}{1-nt^2} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{\left(1-m t^2\right)\left(1-t^2\right) }}$$

You will probably not be able to simplify your result further.

Comment: Ok, so how do I evaluate that to a numerical result?  e.g. Assume integrating between 0 and 2pi.

Comment: @relayman, depends. What computing environment are you using?

Comment: Pen and paper, doing it by hand.

Comment: @relayman, then, unless you have access to tables of the elliptic integral of the third kind (e.g. the ones in Abramowitz and Stegun), or willing to use a numerical quadrature method, then you can't really do much with pen and paper.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician   Ok, I found a copy of "Handbook of Mathematical Functions" by Abramowitz and Stegun. It is a doosey at 1060 pages.  http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~aps/research/projects/as/resources/AandS-letter-v1-2.pdf. Page 599 has Elliptic Integrals of the third Kind.  Not sure what to do from there.

Comment: @relayman357 You can use wolframalpha.com; it is a scaled down, less capable version of Mathematica that would be able to evaluate this.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Ok, I've tried to follow along in the A&S handbook but I'm not sure how to proceed.  Here is what I've got so far:  http://relayman.org/temp/_4_jm/calc.pdf    I would appreciate if you can help me figure out how to perform the computations they prescribe.  I'm stuck at clause 17.7.9

Comment: @JamalS  Thank you.  I ran the integral at wolframalpha.com and it gave a result that has an E(x|m+nsin(2x)) which is apparently notation for an elliptic integral of the second kind.  I have no idea how to process that.  Can you point me to book or information?  I don't have the magic decoder ring.

Comment: @relayman, I'm a bit swamped at the moment; I promise to look into it when I find time.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a product: it's an [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_third_kind) (of the third kind, according to Legendre's scheme), defined by
$$ \Pi(n;\varphi \mid m) = \int_0^{\sin{\varphi}} \frac{dt}{(1-nt^2)\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-mt^2)}}. $$
More information about elliptic integrals may be found on Wikipedia, [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheThirdKind.html), the [DLMF pages](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.2), or the book *Modern Analysis* by Whittaker and Watson (published in the 1920s, now freely available online), Chapter 22. Be aware that the notation varies by source: some use $k^2$ instead of $m$, or something else instead of $\sin{\varphi}$.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108659) is a short discussion of the various (confusing) notations for elliptic integrals. In addition to what was said there: some computing systems use $x=\sin\varphi$ instead of the *amplitude* $\varphi$ as one of the arguments. And particularly in the case of the elliptic integral of the third kind, the characteristic $n$ is sometimes changed to $\alpha^2=n$.