# Does the Incomplete Beta function have forms of Elliptic E besides $\frac14 \text B_{\sin^2(2x)}\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)=\text E(x,2)$?

Tags: special-functions, transformation, periodic-functions, beta-function, elliptic-integrals

**Goal:**

To find more special cases of the [**Incomplete Beta function $\text B_z(a,b)$**](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/) in terms of [**Elliptic $\text E(x,k)$**](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticE2/) using Mathematica notation:

The goal is to find values of:

$$\text B_z(a,b)=\int z^{a-1}(1-z)^{b-1}dz\mathop=^\text{set}\int\sqrt{1-k\sin^2(x)}dx=\text E(x,k);a,b\in\Bbb R,k\ne 0,1$$

The only values for $k\ne 0,1$ found is:

$$\frac14 \text B_{\sin^2(2x)}\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)=\text E(x,2) $$

and

$$\frac58 \text B_{\sin^2(2x)}\left(\frac32,\frac34\right)=\text E(x,2)-\frac12\sin(2x)\cos^\frac32(2x) $$

which may or may not be simplified with [parameter transformation formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3363348/elliptic-integrals-derivation-of-the-imaginary-modulus-transformation)

**Motivation:**

The following formulas use [Elliptic $\text F(x,k)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticF/) and contain $k=-1,\frac12,2,\sqrt[\pm3]{-1}$ with the [principal root](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=principal+root):

$$\frac14\text B_{\sin^2(2x)}\left(\frac12,\frac14\right)=\text F(x,2)$$

$$\frac14\text B_{\sin^4(x)}\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)=\text F(x,-1)$$

$$\frac{i}{\sqrt 2}\left(\frac12\text B_{\sec^4(x)}\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)-\text L\right)=\text F\left(x,\frac12\right)$$

$$\frac{\sqrt[12]{-1}}{2\cdot3^\frac34}\text B_\frac{3\sqrt3i}{\left(1+\sqrt[3]{-1}-3\csc^2(x)\right)^3}\left(\frac16,\frac12\right)=\text F\left(x,\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)$$

which work for the first positive period of the elliptic integrals where [$\text L=$the Lemniscate Constant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=leminscate+constant+)

but are there any other formulas for EllipticE? Please correct me and give me feedback!

**More Motivation:**

It looks like using $a,b\in\{\frac n2,\frac n3,\frac n4,\frac n6\},n\in\Bbb N$ gives elliptic integrals. Here are some identities involving [Inverse Weierstrass P $\wp^{-1}(z;a,b)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/InverseWeierstrassP/) which unfortunately only are the Elliptic F function from above, not Elliptic E:

$$-\frac{\text B_\frac{a}{4z^2}\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}{2\sqrt2\sqrt[4]a}=\wp^{-1}(z;a,0)$$

$$-\frac{(-1)^\frac23\text B_{-\frac{4z^3}b}\left(\frac13,\frac12\right)}{3\cdot2^\frac23\sqrt[6]b}-\frac{2\omega_2}{\sqrt 3\sqrt[6]b}=\wp^{-1}(z;0,-b)$$

$$-\frac{\text B_\frac b{4z^3}\left(\frac16,\frac12\right)}{3\cdot2^\frac23\sqrt[6]b}=\wp^{-1}(z;0,b)$$

with [$\omega_2=$Omega-$2$ Constant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=omega2+constant)

**Reason:**
The final destination is to invert any other special cases to help find the:

> [Inverse of elliptic integral of second kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123360/inverse-of-elliptic-integral-of-second-kind?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C97.9632)

using [Inverse Beta Regularized](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inversebetaregularized), but it is simpler to use the Incomplete Beta function because it is more familiar. Your answer will get credit of course.

If there are no other special cases for $$\text B_z(a,b)=\text E(x,k) $$

then please prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the reciprocal modulus transformation to characterize $E\left(x,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ as a sum of two incomplete beta functions.

Recall the reciprocal modulus transformation (proof in the appendix):

$$E\left(\phi,\frac{1}{p} \right)  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}E\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin \phi}{\sqrt{p}}\right),p\right)-\frac{1-\sqrt{p}^2}{\sqrt{p}}F\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin \phi}{\sqrt{p}}\right),p\right)$$

If we put $p=2$
and using

$$\frac14 \text B_{\sin^2(2x)}\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)=\text E(x,2) $$

and

$$\frac14\text B_{\sin^2(2x)}\left(\frac12,\frac14\right)=\text F(x,2)$$

\begin{align*}E\left(\phi,\frac{1}{2} \right)  = &\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}E\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin \phi}{\sqrt{2}}\right),2\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}F\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin \phi}{\sqrt{2}}\right),2\right)\\
=& \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}B_{\sin^2\left(2\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin \phi}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)}\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)+ \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}} B_{\sin^2\left(2\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin \phi}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)}\left(\frac12,\frac14\right)\\
=& \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}B_{1-\cos^4(\phi)}\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)+ \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}} B_{1-\cos^4(\phi)}\left(\frac12,\frac14\right)
\end{align*}

So the incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind with $\displaystyle k=\frac{1}{2}$ is also related to the incomplete beta function through the following sum:

$$\boxed{E\left(\phi, \frac{1}{2} \right)  = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}B_{1-\cos^4(\phi)}\left(\frac12,\frac34\right)+ \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}} B_{1-\cos^4(\phi)}\left(\frac12,\frac14\right)} $$

**Edit (Appendix): Proof of the reciprocal modulus transformation.**

We will use the notation from Wolfram:

$$F(\alpha,m ) = \int_{0}^{\alpha} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-m\sin^2\alpha}}$$
Typically, the reciprocal modulus transformation is used to transform modulus exceeding the unity to the standard modulus form $0<p\leq 1$. However, nothing prevent us to use it the other way around:

\begin{align*} E\left(\phi,\frac{1}{p} \right) = &\int_{0}^{\phi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{p}\sin^2\theta }} d\theta \\
=& \int_{0}^{\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin\phi}{\sqrt{p}}\right)} \frac{\sqrt{p}\cos^2\varphi }{\sqrt{1-p\sin^2\varphi }} d\varphi  \quad \left( \sin\varphi \mapsto \frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{p}}\right)\\
=& \sqrt{p}F\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin \phi}{\sqrt{p}}\right),p\right) - \sqrt{p}\int_{0}^{\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin\phi}{\sqrt{p}}\right)} \frac{\sin^2\varphi }{\sqrt{1-p\sin^2\varphi }} d\varphi
\end{align*}
The last integral is known as $D(\alpha,p)$ and has the solution.

$$ D(\alpha,p) = \int_{0}^{\alpha} \frac{\sin^2\varphi }{\sqrt{1-p\sin^2\varphi }} d\varphi = \frac{F(\alpha,p)-E(\alpha,p)}{p}$$

(To prove this just apply the standard definition to the right hand side.)

So

\begin{align*} E\left(\phi,\frac{1}{p} \right)   =& \sqrt{p}F\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin \phi}{\sqrt{p}}\right),p\right) - \sqrt{p}\int_{0}^{\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin\phi}{\sqrt{p}}\right)} \frac{\sin^2\varphi }{\sqrt{1-p\sin^2\varphi }} d\varphi\\
=& \sqrt{p}F\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin \phi}{\sqrt{p}}\right),p\right) - \frac{F\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{\phi}{\sqrt{p}}\right),p\right)-E\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin \phi}{\sqrt{p}}\right),p\right)}{\sqrt{p}}\\
=&  \frac{1}{\sqrt{p}} E\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin \phi}{\sqrt{p}}\right),p\right)-\frac{1-p}{\sqrt{p}}F\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin \phi}{\sqrt{p}}\right),p\right) 
\end{align*}

Comment: @TymaGaidash it seems that k=2,1/2 (using Wolfram notation) are the only values that works but I'm continue looking for another transformation

Comment: Where did you find this specific reciprocal modulus transformation?

Comment: Hi @TymaGaidash. It is a relatively well known result for elliptic integrals. One reference is the proposition 114.01 in Friedman and Byrd (1971) *Handbook of Elliptic Integrals for Engineers and Scientists*. I added the proof in the appendix.