# Weierstrass Zeta $\zeta(x;a,b)$ inverse

Tags: special-functions, closed-form, inverse-function, beta-function, elliptic-functions

**Case 1:**

It is [known](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%281%2F6%29+beta%28Inversebetaregularized%28%283+e%5E%281%2F6%29+1.7%29%2F%282+Im%28%CF%89_1%29%29+-+2%2C1%2F3%2C+1%2F2%29%2C+2%2F3%2C+1%2F2%29%2F%286+2%5E%281%2F3%29%29%2Be%5E%281%2F6%29%2Fbaxter+constant-weierstrasszeta%281.7%2C%7B0%2C-e%7D%29) that:

$$\sqrt[6]b\left(\frac{\text B_{\text I^{-1}_{\frac{3\sqrt[6]bx}{2\text{Im}(\omega_1)}-2}\left(\frac13,\frac12\right)}\left(\frac23,\frac12\right)}{6\sqrt[3]2}+\frac1{\text B}\right)=\zeta(x;0,-b) $$ with the [Baxter B](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BaxterConstant.html) and [$\omega_1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=Im%28omega_1%29) constants along with the [**Weierstrass zeta $\zeta(x;a,b)$**](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/WeierstrassZeta/), [incomplete beta $\text B_z(a,b)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/) and [**inverse $\text I^{-1}_x(a,b)$**](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseBetaRegularized/) [beta regularized $\text I_x(a,b$)](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/BetaRegularized/) functions. $\text I^{-1}_x\left(\frac13,\frac12\right)$ is expressible in terms of $\wp(x;a,b)$. Similarly, including [inverse Weierstrass P $\wp^{-1}(x;a,b)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/InverseWeierstrassP/), there are [**conversion formulas $(1)$**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440926/does-the-incomplete-beta-function-have-forms-of-elliptic-e-besides-frac14-tex) for $\text B_x(a,b)$ into $\wp^{-1}(x;a,b)$.

However, using these formulas and [this recurrence relation](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/16/01/01/) gives results for $a-n=\frac13,\frac14,\frac16,b=n+\frac12,n\in\Bbb N$, but not $a=\frac23$. Even using this [**parameter transformation $(2)$**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=Beta%5Bz%2C+a%2C+b%5D%2C%28z%5Ea+%28%281%2Fz%29%5E%28a+%2B+b%29+%28-z%29%5E%28a+%2B+b%29+Beta%5B1%2Fz%2C+1+-+a+-+b%2C+b%5D+%2B+Beta%5Ba%2C+1+-+a+-+b%5D%29%29%2F%28-z%29%5Ea+) cannot put $\text B_z\left(\frac23,\frac12\right)$ in terms of $\wp^{-1}(x;a,b)$. Therefore, the inverse of $\zeta(x;0,b)$ likely is inexpressible in terms of Weierstrass elliptic functions. Luckily, we have

$$\boxed{\zeta(y;0,b)=x\implies y=\frac{2\text{Im}(\omega_1)}{3\sqrt[6]{-b}}\left(\text I_{\text I^{-1}_{\frac{2\text Bx}{\sqrt[6]{-b}}-2}\left(\frac23,
\frac12\right)}\left(\frac13,\frac12\right)+2\right)=\frac{2^{-\frac23}\text B_{\text I^{-1}_{2\left(\frac{\text Bx}{\sqrt[6]{-b}}\omega_1-1\right)}\left(\frac23,\frac12\right)}\left(\frac13,\frac12\right)+4\text{Im}(\omega_1)}{3\sqrt[6]{-b}},\frac{\sqrt[6]{-b}}{\text B}\le x\le \frac{3\sqrt[6]{-b}}{2\text B} }\tag3$$

Test it [**here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=weierstrasszeta%28%282+Im%28omega_1%29+%28betaregularized%28inversebetaregularized%282+baxter*1.2+%2Fe%5E%281%2F6%29-2%2C2%2F3%2C+1%2F2%29%2C1%2F3%2C+1%2F2%29+%2B+2+%29%29%2F%283+e%5E%281%2F6%29%29%2C%7B0%2C-e%7D%29). We could use the [$\omega_2$ constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Omega-2Constant.html):

$$-\frac{(-1)^\frac23\text B_{-\frac{4z^3}b}\left(\frac13,\frac12\right)}{3\cdot2^\frac23\sqrt[6]b}-\frac{2\omega_2}{\sqrt 3\sqrt[6]b}=\wp^{-1}(z;0,-b) $$

**Case 2:**

appears with the [complex conjugate $z$](https://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/sigma%20complex%20number%20leaflets/sigma-complex6-2009-1.pdf) and [ubiquitous constant U](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/UbiquitousConstant.html):

$$\boxed{\zeta(y;a,0)=z\implies y=-\frac{\overline {\text B_\frac1{\text I^{-1}_{\frac{2iz}{\text U\sqrt[4]a}+i+1}\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)}\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)}}{2\sqrt2\sqrt[4]a},z=\frac{\text U\sqrt[4]a}2(i(1-x)-1),0\le x\le 1 }\tag 4$$

Shown [**here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=N%5B%28i+%281-catalan%29-1%29e%5E%281%2F4%29ubiquitousconst%2F2-weierstrasszeta%28-conj%5BBeta%5B1%2FInverseBetaRegularized%5Bcatalan%2C3%2F4%2C+1%2F2%5D%2C1%2F4%2C1%2F2%5D%5D%2F%282%E2%88%9A2+E%5E%281%2F4%29%29%2C%7Be%2C0%7D%29%2C10%5D). Using $(2)$, $\text B_x\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)$ is expressible through [Elliptic F](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticF.html) and $\wp^{-1}(x;a,0)$ while $\text B_x\left(\frac34,\frac12\right)$ is through [**Elliptic E**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticE.html)

**Case 3:**

$$\boxed{\zeta(y;0,b)=z\implies y=\frac{\sqrt[3]2\overline{\text B_\frac1{\text I^{-1}_{i\sqrt3-\frac{2\text B i z}{\sqrt[6]b}+1}\left(\frac23,\frac12\right)}\left(\frac16,\frac12\right)}}{6\sqrt[6]b},z=\frac{\sqrt[6]b((x-1)i+\sqrt3)}{2\text B},0\le x\le1}\tag5$$

[**Shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=%28e%5E%281%2F6%29+%28-i+%2B+sqrt%283%29+%2B+i+catalan+%29%29%2F%282+baxter%29%2Cweierstrasszeta%282%5E%281%2F3%29%2F6+conj%28beta%281%2Finversebetaregularized%28catalan+%2C2%2F3%2C1%2F2%29%2C1%2F6%2C1%2F2%29%29%2Fe%5E%281%2F6%29%2C%7B0%2Ce%7D%29)

Again, using $(2)$, $\text B_x\left(\frac16,\frac12\right)$ is expressible in terms of $\wp^{-1}(x;0,b)$

**Question:**

We can extend the domain a little:

$$\text I^{-1}_x\left(a,\frac12\right)=1-\left(2\text I^{-1}_\frac x2(a,a)-1\right)^2 $$

or simplify the $\text B_z(a,b)$ with $(2)$. Unfortunately, $(3),(4),(5)$’s domains are tight and inverting $\zeta(x;a,0)$ involves [inverting Elliptic E](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123360/inverse-of-elliptic-integral-of-second-kind), so no Weierstrass elliptic functions. How can one use [**symmetries and periodicity**](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/WeierstrassZeta/04/02/), etc. to invert, likely with $a$ or $b=0$, $\zeta(x;a,b)$ in closed form?