# Find $\int{\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{b+a\cos\theta}}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Trying to find:
$$\int{\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{b+a\cos\theta}}}$$
(generalizing the cases for $a,b = 1$).

I've tried two approaches, none of which have gotten me far:

1. By noticing that $\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\sqrt{b+a\cos\theta}\right) = \frac{-a\sin\theta}{2\sqrt{b+a\cos\theta}}$, I rewrote the integral as
   $$\int{\frac2{-a\sin\theta}\frac{-a\sin\theta}{2\sqrt{b+a\cos\theta}}}\,d\theta$$
   Then I used integration by parts ($u= -\frac2a\csc\theta, du = \frac2a\csc\theta\cot\theta \, d\theta,;dv=\frac{-a\sin\theta}{2\sqrt{b+a\cos\theta}}d\theta, v = \sqrt{b+a\cos\theta}$) to yield
   $$-\frac2a\csc\theta\sqrt{b+a\cos\theta} \,- \int{\frac2a\csc\theta\cot\theta \sqrt{b+a\cos\theta}}\,d\theta = -\frac{2\sqrt{b+a\cos\theta}}{a\sin\theta} \,- \int{\frac{2\cos{\theta}\sqrt{b+a\cos\theta}}{a\sin^2{}\theta}}\,d\theta$$
   But I'm not sure where to go from here. u-substitution?
2. By Weierstrass substitution, let $t=\tan{(\frac\theta{2})} \implies \cos\theta = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, d\theta = \frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$
   $$\implies \int{\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{b+a\cos\theta}}} = 
   \int{\frac1{\sqrt{b+a\,\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}}\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}}$$
   $$\int\frac{2dt}{\sqrt{b(1+t^2)+a(1-t^2)}\cdot\sqrt{1+t^2}}$$
   But this is very quickly becoming a mess.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If I recall correctly, this is one of the integrals that is not solvable in elementary functions...

Comment: This antiderivative is given in terms of a [Elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), which in general is non-elementary. So except for a handful of special cases, there's no hope of a solution using elementary methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [integrating incomplete elliptic integral of first kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480298/integrating-incomplete-elliptic-integral-of-first-kind)