# the integral similar to elliptic integral with upper limit is π instead of π/2

Tags: mathematica, elliptic-integrals

G'day, mate. I wonder...
Is it possible to obtain the value of this integral?
$$\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1+b^2\sin^2(x)}\,dx,\text{where b is positive real number.} $$
And I turned to Mathematica's aid, and it gave me the result:
$$2E(-b^2) $$
where E is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind;(why?? but its upper limit is π instead of π/2.) It didn't give me a step-by-step solution, so I still don't understand how it solved it. Plus, I doubt if this result is incorrect, since even rewriting the integral as:$$\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1-(-b^2)\sin^2(x)}\,dx$$it still doesn't match the form of the complete elliptic integral of the second kind:$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2(x)}\,dx$$The most confusing part is that$$k^2=-b^2$$ it's impossible since b is a positive real number! I'm so confused, hope someone can help me out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint, what is $\sin(\pi-x)$ and why is this the double of the integral from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}2$?

Comment: Have you tried using the half-angle formula? $\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$. I don't know if it answers your question, it's just an idea :)

Comment: btw for mathematica  $E\left(\varphi \,|\,k^2\right) = E(\sin\varphi;k) = \int_0^\varphi \sqrt{1-k^2 \sin^2\theta}\, d\theta$ so that replacing $k^2$ by $-k^2\cdots$

Comment: @Martingalo thank you but if go this way,$$\sqrt{(1+\frac{b^2}{2})-\frac{b^2}{2}\cos(2x)}\,dx$$, we still can’t open the square root.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni hi, hmm I’m not familiar with the elliptic integrals, so I guess you mean $$2E(-b^2)$$ is correct, right?

Comment: Yes! My first tip about $\sin(\pi-x)$ should help you to rewrite your integral as the integral over $(\frac{\pi}2,\pi)$ added to the integral over $(0,\frac{\pi}2)$ (prove that they are equal). By definition $E\left(\varphi \,|\,-b^2\right) = \int_0^\varphi \sqrt{1+b^2 \sin^2\theta}\, d\theta$ so that mma is right! To obtain $k^2=-b^2$ you need $b=\pm i k$ so that you are in fact replacing $k$ by (say) $i b$. Hoping this clarified things,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni hi, I came up with a method and finally solved it! But my answer is $$2\sqrt{1+b^2}E(\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+b^2}})$$

Comment: In fact $\displaystyle E(i b)=2\sqrt{1+b^2}E\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right)$ if you use the definition $E(k):=\int_0^\varphi \sqrt{1-k^2 \sin^2\theta}\, d\theta$ (and not mathematica's definition writing this as $E(k^2)$ i.e. squaring the parameter of $E$)

Comment: (mma and alpha use the parameter $m=k^2$ convention while more usual definitions use the modulus $k$. This is detailed in JM's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108575/what-does-mean/108659#108659) )

Comment: Mma's convention for the previous functional identity would thus be $\displaystyle E[ -b^2]=\sqrt{1+b^2}E\left[\frac{b^2}{1+b^2}\right]\;$ but this is simply the second identity [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticE/17/01/) for $z:=-b^2$. (sorry my initial functional identity should have been $\displaystyle E(i b)=\sqrt{1+b^2}E\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right)$ without the $2$).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni thanks for your conscientious discussion!

Comment: Glad it helped @MilneAndo !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let$$\chi=\int^\pi_0 \sqrt{1+b^2\big[1-\cos^2(x)\big]}{\rm d}x=
\int^\pi_0 \sqrt{1+b^2}\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{1+b^2}\cos^2(x)}\,{\rm d}x$$
Here let$$k^2=\frac{b^2}{1+b^2}$$and separate the integral into two parts, so
$$\chi=\sqrt{1+b^2}\bigg[\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 \sqrt{1-k^2\cos^2(x)\,}{\rm d}x+
\int^\pi_\frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{1-k^2\cos^2(x)\,}{\rm d}x\bigg]$$
For the former one, let
$$\cos(x)\big|^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 =\sin\big(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\big)=\sin(z')\big|^0_\frac{\pi}{2}$$
For the latter one, let
$$\cos(x)\big|^\pi_\frac{\pi}{2} =-\sin\big(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\big)=-\sin(z)\big|^\frac{\pi}{2}_0$$
After some efforts and obtain
$$\chi=\sqrt{1+b^2}\big[E(k)+E(k)\big]$$